# Does someone know the lever-style efficiency of a wedge considered in ideal physics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I do not want guesses. I have heard that a typical wedge or even a reverse wedge has a mechanical efficiency of 1.25 when compared to a leverage ratio of (1,2,3, etc.).

Has anyone else heard of this number before?

I am talking about a multiplier of mass * inputted momentum or something along those lines. It would typically involve altitude loss which is not accounted in this number. It is not an over-unity value, but a value used for determining mechanical advantage.

What if the wedge is propelled for example, purely on the horizontal? Would the door, etc that interacted with it be propelled initially faster than the momentum applied to the wedge? Would it be fair to call this effect the effect of an inclined plane? (Possibly not?)

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: "I do not want guesses" - that is very difficult when your question, your scenario and your definitions are so unclear. I think you must either accept that answerers must partly guess at your meaning *or* you must make your question much clearer.

Comment: I was simply asking for someone with more experience with the mechanics of wedges. Are they analogous to levers or not? And if so, how do they compare? I know in the simple sense they are not the same machine, but mechanically they're supposed to speak the universal language of mechanics, so the 1.25X rating seemed plausible at least with some gradients. I know some basic things about calculating gradients, but applying gradients to wedges confuses me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's not a specific problem, it's a general problem of the mechanical advantage of wedges. You could provide a general range if you knew about it.

Comment: Additional information: What I am guessing is that a mechanical advantage of 1.25 corresponds with a particular gradient of the wedge, even when the wedge is propelled purely horizontally. I would guess this gradient is approximately 50% of a 22.5 degree angle, which equals 11.25 degrees. This is an approximation of the typical angle of a wedge as related to a 45 degree angle. So, I suppose a wedge of 11.25 degrees propelled purely horizontally would convey an ideal force of 1.25X the ratio of masses.

Comment: Provided sturdy bearing, up to < 1.25X the gravitational force acting on the wedge could be communicated to another object. Any problem with this?

Answer (score 2):

For an ideal frictionless wedge or [inclined plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclined_plane), the mechanical advantage (the ratio of weight to input force) is the sloping length of the wedge divided by its vertical height. In terms of the angle $\theta$ of the wedge this is $\frac 1 {\sin \theta}$. A mechanical advantage of $1.25$ is achieved with an angle of $\sin^{-1} 0.8$, which is $53.13$ degrees. A shallower angle will give a greater mechanical advantage and vice versa.

In practice, the effect of friction means that the actual mechanical advantage depends on the angle of the wedge, the coefficient of friction between the object and the wedge, and also on whether you are only holding the object in place or whether you are using the wedge to raise it.